# How can I change the value of 'Setting' name attribute using powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

How can I change the value of 'Setting' name attribute using powershell script

XML

**

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
  <Role name="Role1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="enableCounter" value="true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <Role name="Role2">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="enableCounter" value="true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration >
```

**

I've a script like this, it is not working

```
$serviceconfigpath= "D:\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg"
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($serviceconfigpath)

$testValue= "test"

foreach($n in $doc.selectnodes("/ServiceConfiguration/Role"))
{
    foreach($n in $doc.selectnode("/ServiceConfiguration/Role/ConfigurationSettings/Setting"))
    {
        switch($n.name)
        {
            "enableCounter" { $n.value = $testValue}
        }
    }
}

$doc.Save($serviceconfigpath)
```

Comment: Your XML is broken. There are missing `</ConfigurationSettings>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the XML and use `XmlNamespaceManager` to access the document:

```
$nsMgr = new-object xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
$doc.selectnodes("/ServiceConfiguration/Role/ConfigurationSettings/Setting", $nsMgr)
```

Comment: it is fixed now. May I know your comments on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can do what you want. You can write ii shorter, I detailled everything, just to explain.

```
$testValue= "test"

# Read the XML file
$file = Get-Content "c:\temp\FileBefore.xml"

# See it as an XMLDocument
$xml = [xml] $file

foreach ($role in $xml.ServiceConfiguration.role)
{
  # name before
  $role.ConfigurationSettings.Setting.name
  # modification
  $role.ConfigurationSettings.Setting.name = $testValue
  # name after
  $role.ConfigurationSettings.Setting.name  
}

# Save it back to a file
$xml.Save("c:\temp\FileAfter.xml")
```

JP

Comment: it is not working i've cscfg file which is the service configuration of windows azure cloud service.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry Sunil, if you copy/past the XML you give us it works. You certainly need to adapt to yours XML or give the final file.